# How Garbage collector in V8 treats Promises when assigned to a new object(shallow copy)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, garbage-collection, sequelize.js

```
let appLogin = null;
    SomeModel.findOne({
            where: {id: req.user.id},
            attributes: ["id","property_id"],
            raw: true,
        })
        .then((login) => {
            if(!login){
                throw new CustomErrors.InvalidToken("ER401");
            }             
            appLogin = login; return null;
        }
        .then((nullRecieved) => {
            console.log(appLogin)   
        })
        .catch((error) => {console.log(error)})
```

I'm facing a memory leak issue, and started debugging recently, resolved few things. But it seems I have to more concern about object references and garbage collections, in above code sample, `SomeModel.findOne` returns a promise, I'm assigning that promise to a new object(shallow copy) `appLogin`. Should I make the deep copy of that promise? Pretty confused about the promise references to new object, will garbage collector treat that promise as garbage after going to the next .then()?  Thanks in advance. : )

Comment: Assignment does not cause a shallow copy to be made. Also, neither `login` nor `appLogin` is a Promise. Both are references to an object delivered by the Promise returned by `SomeModel.findOne()`.

Comment: Yep, those are not promise, but should i be concerned about the references for garbage collection process?

Comment: Mmm, there are people better qualified to answer but as far as I can tell, there should be no memory leak here. If there was, then many if not most promise chains would be leaky.